# How to loop user input in Python Selenium if the input is invalid

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the user input to be only taken if it is in the element. I can't seem to figure it out when I enter an invalid input the progam just stops doing anything instead of looping to ask tell the user to enter a valid input.

I tried the NoSuchElementException but it didn't do anything as well.There are many inputs that can be taken but if the input that the user is given does nothing I don't want it to be taken.
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrIwj.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read this. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please copy paste your code instead of a picture. [read here why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want to reenter the value from the user if the value is incorrect For that We can use a continuous loop `while True` to repeatedly ask for input until a valid input is provided.

Your code will be like below:

```
# Use an infinite loop to repeatedly ask for input until valid

while True:
    #Entering Tenant name
    try:
        tenantname = input('Enter Tenant name: ')
        tenantsearch = driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id="render-wrapper"]/div/div[3]/div/div/di")
        tenantsearch.send_keys(tenantname)
        #Clicking Tenant
        dropdown = driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="Button")
        i = 0
        while i < len(dropdown):
            if(dropdown[i] text == tenantname):
                dropdoun[i].click()
                i=i+1
        #Clicking Inventory feeds tab
        inv_tab = driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@i")
        inv_tab.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        break # Break the infinite loop when everything goes smoothly
    except NosuchElementException:
        print("Sorry, I didn’t understand that.")
```

Concept of While True which means a continues/Infinite Loop by default it will ask use for input every time whether it is correct or not but we use break statement when there is valid input which will break the continues/Infinite Loop

So when every the input is not correct it will goes under the loop and if the input is correct it will break the loop